# How can i check if the date is today and then print specific text using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```css
.today-tag {margin-left:10px;color:red};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="day">Sunday<span class="today-tag"></span></div>
<div class="day">Monday<span class="today-tag"></span></div>
<div class="day">Tuesday<span class="today-tag"></span></div>
<div class="day">Wedsday<span class="today-tag"></span></div>
<div class="day">Thursday<span class="today-tag"></span></div>
<div class="day">Friday<span class="today-tag"></span></div>
<div class="day">Saturday<span class="today-tag"></span></div>
```

and i want to add the word "TODAY" next to the current day of the week. Is there a way to check if the date is today using jquery ? I already tried something like that but it didn't work.

```
var getdate = new Date();

if(getdate == new Date()) {
$('.today-tag').text("TODAY")
}
```

In my php file i use this code to output the open/close hours of a store:

```
<?php if ( $res=FunctionsV3::getMerchantOpeningHours($merchant_id)):?>
<?php foreach ($res as $val):?>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-4 "></i> 
 <?php echo t($val['day'])?>
 <span class="today-tag"></span>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 "><?php echo $val['hours']?></div>
 <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3"><?php echo $val['open_text']?></div>
 </div>
 <?php endforeach;?>
 <?php else :?>
 <p class="text-danger"><?php echo t("Not available.")?></p>
 <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: First of all, `id` is a unique property, it can't be assigned to multiple `span` element

Comment: You have multiple IDs of the sane name - invalid HTML.

Comment: @rv7 my mistake i edited my code and changed id to class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
$('.today-tag').remove();
$("#d" + n).append('<span class="today-tag">TODAY</span>');
```

```css
.today-tag {margin-left:10px;color:red};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d0" class="day">Sunday</div>
<div id="d1" class="day">Monday</div>
<div id="d2" class="day">Tuesday</div>
<div id="d3" class="day">Wednesday</div>
<div id="d4" class="day">Thursday</div>
<div id="d5" class="day">Friday</div>
<div id="d6" class="day">Saturday</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, just for fun.

```js
var today = new Date().getDay();
var days = [
    'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wedsday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'
];
var daysContainer = document.getElementById('days');
days.forEach((day, index) => {
    day = today === index ? day + ' today': day;
    daysContainer.innerHTML += `
        <div class="day">${day}<span class="today-tag"></span></div>
    `;
});
```

```css
#today-tag {margin-left:10px;color:red};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="days"></section>
```

Comment: it doesnt print the text "TODAY" next to the current day of week

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [moment](https://momentjs.com) when ever I need to do anything about Date & Time. So I usually create a method like this :

```
function compareDate (dateData, duration) {
    let currentDate = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
     // Below condition will filter time if included, only compare dates
     // You can ignore this condition if you want to compare Time as well.
     if (dateData.toString().includes("T")) {
        dateData = dateData.toString().substring(0, dateData.indexOf("T"))
     }
    return moment(dateData).isSame(currentDate, duration)
}
```

And call it like this :

```
let isToday = compareDate("2018-03-12" , "today")
console.log(isToday)
```

You can use this for other durations as well like :

```
// Will check if given date is in current week or not
let isThisWeek = compareDate("2018-03-12" , "week")
console.log(isThisWeek) 

// Will check if given date is in current month or not
let isThisMonth = compareDate("2018-03-12" , "month")
console.log(isThisMonth) 


// Will check if given date is in current year or not
let isThisYear = compareDate("2018-03-12" , "year")
console.log(isThisYear)
```

Comment: Is there any jsfiddle example to see this in action? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily, just add separate IDs to each `<span>` first:

```js
$(function()
{
    $("#day-" + new Date().getDay()).append("Today!");
})
```

```css
.day > span {
    margin-left:10px;
    color:red
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="day">
    Sunday <span id="day-0"></span>
</div>
<div class="day">
    Monday <span id="day-1"></span>
</div>
<div class="day">
    Tuesday <span id="day-2"></span>
</div>
<div class="day">
    Wednesday <span id="day-3"></span>
</div>
<div class="day">
    Thursday <span id="day-4"></span>
</div>
<div class="day">
    Friday<span id="day-5"></span>
</div>
<div class="day">
    Saturday<span id="day-6"></span>
</div>
```

```
<div class="day">Sunday<span id="day-0"></span></div>
<div class="day">Monday<span id="day-1"></span></div>
<div class="day">Tuesday<span id="day-2"></span></div> 
<!--And so on...-->
```

Then do this in your script:

```
$(function() {
    $("#day" + new Date().getDay()).append(" is today!");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get today's day index using [Date.getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) and then add HTML to the corresponding `span.today-tag`

```js
var today = new Date().getDay(); // returns the index of today

$(function() {
  $('.today-tag').eq(today).text('TODAY');
});
```

```css
.today-tag {
  margin-left:10px;
  color:red
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="day">Sunday<span class="today-tag"></span></div>
<div class="day">Monday<span class="today-tag"></span></div>
<div class="day">Tuesday<span class="today-tag"></span></div>
<div class="day">Wedsday<span class="today-tag"></span></div>
<div class="day">Thursday<span class="today-tag"></span></div>
<div class="day">Friday<span class="today-tag"></span></div>
<div class="day">Saturday<span class="today-tag"></span></div>
```

Comment: It works perfect here and in jsfiddle but if i upload the code on my server it prints the text "TODAY " next to "Monday" instead of "Sunday" !!! Any idea why???

Comment: It could due to the server-script. Can you post the code?